# how to specify text box height in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

in cakePHP how do i specify the height of the test box ,i know the width part.
my code looks like this for text box:

```
echo $this->Form->Input('moduleName',array('label' => 'Title','style'=>'width:800px;'));
```

Comment: you can just use `width:800px; height:100px;`. Unless you're talking about a textarea, in which case you can also set the `rows` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Really simple:
`echo $this->Form->input('moduleName', array('label' => 'Title', 'style' => 'width: 800px; height: 50px;'));`

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess he might be talking about a textarea in which case the following code works:

```
echo $this->Form->input('moduleName', array(
    'label' => 'Title',
    'rows' => 3,
    'style' => 'width: 800px;',
));
```